# Is it possible to edit a Vector3 in the inspector by clicking on the scene?

Tags: unity, editors

I have a component that represents an NPC that patrols between several waypoints.

Initially I represented each waypoint as a simple Vector3, so the component had a serialized field of type Vector3[]. However, it required me to edit the x, y and z values of each waypoint manually.

Alternatively, I could represent each waypoint as a Transform, so the component had a serialized field of type Transform[]. Then, I could create an object for each waypoint, place it wherever I want on the scene, and then drag it into the waypoints array of the component. However, this requires me to create many game objects - one for each waypoint of each patroller - where I do not really need the objects, I only need the position.

Is there another way to edit a Vector3 field by clicking on the scene view?

Comment: Would it help you to at least visualize the route ba drawing lines between them while in edit mode? I wrote a script for that once and found it pretty helpful.

Comment: Presumably you considered writing a custom editor for this using [Handles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html)? What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Philipp yes, it would help.

Comment: @DMGregory no, I do  not know much about writing custom editors - I wanted to know if there is a built-in way to do it.

Comment: The Handles class is the built-in way to do it.

Comment: @DMGregory OK, thanks, I did not know what to search. I will study this.